# How to record video in background when having video calling in application

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application that will be use to record video in background once the video calling starts.I googled about it but didn't get any solution. Many articles say that it is not possible.

**Please let me know the way to implement the functionality**

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you can simply record the screen of the phone. There are several libraries available for implementing that. You can trigger or alert the library to start recording the screen once the video call starts.

Comment: I am able to record the screen but with that I want to capture the audio as well.

Comment: In that case, use mediarecorder class for recording the output of the speaker and the mic.

Comment: I am using media recorder class but its not working.